# SQL WHERE clause with parameter - NULL should match depending on parameter value

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am writing a query with a parameter.

- if my parameter is 1, then match all lines equal to 1 and equal to NULL
- if my parameter is 2, then only get equal to 2

So far, I only have something like this:

```
Select * From Table a  
Where a.Column1 = @Value
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is all the rows where `a.Column1 = @Value` and `null`s only if `@Value = 1`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE (@Value = 1 AND Column1 IS NULL)
   OR (Column1 = @Value)
```